# Find and delete almost duplicates rows

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have an SQL table with *id* of a vane, the *received message time*, and the *wind speed*.
I found the vane sending a duplicates of wind speed, after a second.
There are about a 2-3 duplicates each time, how can i find/remove these records?

As you can see in the screen-shot, wind-speed of 12.6132 exist 3 times, at:
161960999**1000**
161960999**2000**
161960999**3000**

I need to delete 2 of them, not really matter which one

[image: The table wth the duplicates]

Comment: Provide a sample AS CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (10 rows enough) and show desired output with some explanations. Do not forget to specify **precise** criteria for deletion (the rows differs in timestamp so storing the least value seems to be the most suitable).

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```sql
DELETE t1
FROM `table` t1
JOIN `table` t2 USING (id, windSpeed)
LEFT JOIN `table` t3 USING (id)
WHERE t1.receivedAt > t3.receivedAt
  AND t3.receivedAt > t2.receivedAt
  AND t1.windSpeed != t3.windSpeed
  AND t3.id IS NULL
```

I hope that `windSpeed` datatype is DECIMAL, not FLOAT or DOUBLE.